Are Catholics allowed to oppose women holding public office?
Are Catholics allowed to oppose women holding public office?
related question: Are Catholics allowed to oppose women's suffrage?

Particular women or women in general?

This probably wasn't a good time to ask this question, but yes, women in general.

The greatest, most authoritative doctor of the Church, St. Thomas Aquinas, did.
Kristin M. Popik, The Philosophy of Woman of St. Thomas Aquinas, Part Two: The Role of Woman, §"Women Outside Domestic Society":

Within civil society, women, according to Aquinas, have no public role. Since their proper sphere of activity is the internal affairs of the household, they must not concern themselves with external affairs. They must abstain from civic activities,90 from warfare,91 and even from being lawyers, since public disputation is shameful in a woman just as public teaching is [cf. 1 Tim. 2:12].92 Women are unfit to be civil rulers because of the weakness of their reason:

Nihil differt utrum ipsæ mulieres principentur; vel ipsi principes sub mulieribus regantur, quod eis subiecti sunt propter insolentiam mulierum. Idem enim accidit utroque modo, ut scilicet civitas male regatur quia mulieres deficiunt ratione. … Earum indicia in rebus civilivus, item perniciosa est et nocua.93
[And yet it makes no difference whether the women govern or if the governors themselves are ruled by women, being subject to them because of the extravagance of the women. For the same thing happens in both modes: the city is badly ruled because the women lack reason. … *
*The 2nd part isn't found in the Corpus Thomisticum, but it roughly translates as: "Their [women's] mark in civil matters is also pernicious and harmful."]

Aquinas explains Aristotle's statement that the rule of women is the corruption of the city by saying that reason is the most necessary requirement for rulers, so women, who are deficient in reason, must be subject and not rule.94 The Supplement [of the Summa Theologiæ], however, mentions that women may have temporal rule although they are denied spiritual rule.95 Thomas himself corresponded with women rulers, advising them on matters about which they questioned him. His Letter to the Duchess of Brabant "On the Government of Jews" in its tone and address suggests nothing but respect for the "illustrious and pious Lady (Domina)" who is addressed as "Your Excellency."96 Thomas does not treat her as though she were either weak in reason or unfit for rule. Rather, he respectfully answers her questions, advises her to seek the counsel of others more knowledgeable than he, and wishes her a long reign: "Valeat dominatio vestra per tempora longiora. [May your reign succeed even longer.]"97
Notes
90. In Pol. II, 6.
91. Ibid.; De Reg. Prin. IV, 5 [pp. 229-32].
92. In I ad Cor. XIV, 7, 881.
93. In Pol. II, 13.
94. In I ad Cor. XIV, 7, 880; In IV Sent. 19, 1, 1, 3, ad 4.
95. Suppl., 39, 1, ad 2.
96. De Reg. Judaeorum.
97. Ibid.

There have been great queens in Christendom, such as Queen Blanche of Castile (mother of King St. Louis IX, who ruled as his regent after his father Louis VIII died in a crusade) and Queen Isabella of Spain, "The Last Crusader".
